# problem with saving uploaded image to my file

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

i am able to upload the name of the image file to my database however it wont save to my file

i have tried this code with other system before and it worked well. i'm not sure why it doesnt work on my current system.

in this system, i need to submit the image along with other input as well(other input such as name,address,date,etc) in the same form.

my form code:

```
<form method = "post" action="insert.php">

<label for="name">Full Name</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">

<label for="address">Address</label>
    <textarea id="address" name="address" placeholder="" style="height:100px" class = "form control"></textarea>

//other input field

<label for="picture">Picture</label>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="hidden" name="picture" value="<?php echo $print[0]+1;?>">

<label for="date">Date & Time</label>
  <input type="datetime" name="date" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("countryname"); echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s");?>">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

 </form> 
</form>
```

my upload.php:

```
    $target_file = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $directory = "upload/";
    $uploadOk = 1;

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg") {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } 
    else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $directory)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Your file has successfully been uploaded.'); window.location='insert.php';</script>";
        } 
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.'); window.location='insert.php';</script>";
```

note: `<?php echo $print[0]+1;?>` is to show the last value of auto increment in db

can you point out what i'm doing wrong and the solution? cause i've done so many trial and error and still cant find the answer. thank you so much for your time.

Comment: _“my form code:”_ - you can not nest forms into each other, that is invalid HTML. Go and fix that first of all.

Comment: you should mention `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form element.

Comment: @Gulshan It is mentioned, but in a `form` inside a `form`

Comment: @kerbholz why you use `form` inside `form`? You can manage both save data and upload the image, conditionally on the same function.

Comment: @Gulshan _I_ don't use `form` inside `form`, I'm not OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the `<form>` inside another `<form>`, it won't work. Do the upload and the insert at the same time, otherwise, you need to upload with ajax and then send the path with the submission of the form.

```
<form method = "post" action="upload-and-insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">

    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <textarea id="address" name="address" placeholder="" style="height:100px" class = "form control"></textarea>

//other input field

    <label for="picture">Picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="hidden" name="picture" value="<?php echo $print[0]+1;?>">

    <label for="date">Date & Time</label>
    <input type="datetime" name="date" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("countryname"); echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s");?>">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add enctype to your html form

```
 <form method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```